# Bound for probability of the intersection of a set of events

Tags: probability

There are $N$ random variables $X_1,\dots X_N$ and $Pr(X_i=1)=p$ $\forall i\in N$. Can we upper bound the probability  that all random variables are $1$, i.e., $Pr(X_i=1,\forall i\in N)$. Note that the random variables are not independent.

Edit:
How about a lower bound?
Looking for answers other than $0,1$.

My attempt: I am thinking the product (as if independent) is a upperbound, but not sure.

Comment: Well, 1 is an upper bound (containing very little information).

Comment: @EricTowers you supposedly want something converging to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, like OP's product, which results in $p^N$...

Comment: without additional assumptions you can't do better than $p$, it's optimal for all $X_i$ representing the same r.v.

Comment: @mm-aops $p$ sound good, thanks. Could you also suggestion a lower bound please ? will $p^N$ work for a lower bound?

Comment: it won't, if $p$ is small enough (with respect to $N$) you can get $0$, for example for $p < 1/2$ you can choose disjoint events. if $p$ is larger you can still get $0$, but this will require $N$ to be sufficiently big

Answer (score 9):

You are asking about the intersection of $N$ events.  The simplest bounds are the Frechet inequalities:
$$
P(A_1)+...+P(A_N)-(N-1) \leq P(A_1 \cap... \cap A_N) \leq \min\left[P(A_1), ..., P(A_N) \right]
$$
There are also some more advanced lower bounds in this paper:
http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1426084?uid=3739696&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106787384053

Answer (score 2):

I guess a lower bound on the probability of the intersection can be obtained by the union-bound:

\begin{align}
\textrm{Pr}[\cap_i X_i] &= 1-\textrm{Pr}[\cup_i \overline{X_i}]\\
&\geq1-N\cdot\textrm{Pr}[\overline{X_1}]\\
&=1-N\cdot(1-p)\enspace,
\end{align}
which gives a nontrivial bound for $p>1-\frac{1}{N}$.